# Email cannot be sent with sendgrid(C#) and no trace of Exceptions

Tags: c#, email, sendgrid

I use the `SendAsync` method in my code to trigger Emails. The Email Code is printed below.

```
public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message) {
 if (message.Destination != null)
  await configSendGridasync(message);
}
private async Task configSendGridasync(IdentityMessage message) {
 var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
 myMessage.AddTo(message.Destination);
 myMessage.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailAccount"], "XYC Social");
 myMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
 myMessage.Text = message.Body;
 myMessage.Html = message.Body;

 var credentials = new NetworkCredential(
  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailAccount"],
  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailPassword"]
 );

 // Create a Web transport for sending email.
 var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);

 // Send the email.
 if (transportWeb != null) {
  await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
 } else {
  Trace.TraceError("Failed to create Web transport.");
  await Task.FromResult(0);
 }
}
```

In the controller I use below code to trigger the Email.

```
public async Task < ActionResult > ForgotPassword(XYCSocial.Models.ManageUserViewModel model) {
 IdentityMessage msg = new IdentityMessage {
  " Message",
  Subject = "Reset Password",
  Destination = result.Email
 };
 try {
  await _emailService.SendAsync(msg);
 } catch (Exception ex) {
  ViewBag.Status = "Error : " + ex.Message;
  throw;
 }

 TempData["Success"] = " Some Message";
 return RedirectToAction("Login");
}
} else {
 TempData["Failed"] = "Please enter valid User name";
 return RedirectToAction("Login");
}
} catch (Exception) {


 TempData["Failed"] = "Email Send Failed..Please Try After Some Time";
 return RedirectToAction("Login");
```

However When I call the SendAsync method in the controller for triggering emails it just executes without an error but the Email Is never sent.

Finally after a long time it says:

> Email Send Failed

From the above `TempData["Failed"]` tag. I had verified the suppressions folder in the sendgrid account but there is no sign of Spam, or bad email address, or block, etc.

This same code was working until Feb 17th, 2017  but just doesn't work after that.

Comment: Update : I upgraded the version of  Sendgrid which let me take the APIKEY in the var transportWeb = new Web(APIKEY ); and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same issues using similar code. What I found tonight was an updated sample on the sendgrid GitHub page https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp

This is for the V3 version of Sendgrid Mail.

I can confirm that using this code with an Azure hosted MVC 5 solution works:

```
var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NAME_OF_THE_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_FOR_YOUR_SENDGRID_KEY");
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var from = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User");
        var subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid CSharp SDK!";
        var to = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User");
        var plainTextContent = "Hello, Email!";
        var htmlContent = "<strong>Hello, Email!</strong>";
        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

You would need to replace your entire Config method and add your environment variable inside the Azure portal manager (which you need to get from the Sendgrid site)